How to remove the title from Get.snackbar?
Get.snackbar has the title as a required parameter, so it should be placed.
If we tried to do this: Get.snackbar("", "message");
then there will be an unneeded gap above the message.
I've tried to do this:
Get.snackbar(
   "",
   "snack bar",
   titleText: SizedBox(),
)

but the gap still exists:

Here is what expected:


You can enhance your app's notifications with a stylish snackbar by using this package: https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_snackbar_content

To remove the title from Get.snackbar without a gap:
1. Use Get.rawSnackbar instead
like this:
Get.rawSnackbar(message: "snackbar");


But if you insist on using Get.snackbar for any reason whatsoever, then you can do the following:
2. Overwrite the padding
The snack bar has a default padding so you have to overwrite it.
Get.snackbar(
   "", // title
   "snack bar", // message
   titleText: SizedBox(),
   padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(16.0, 8.0, 16.0, 16.0),
);

explanation:

You have to add the titleText, because the default value of it is a Text widget so it will take a place if you didn't overwrite it, because Text takes place even if it's empty.

The padding of the top should be half of the rest because this padding is applied to the title & the message so the SizedBox will have 8 pixels of padding and the message another 8 pixels, the title doesn't have bottom padding so it won't be affected.



note:
Get.rawSnackbar is just a more customizable snackbar with no much default values in it as the Get.snackbar
